# Make meta + arrows count underscore as words?

Tags: macos, terminal, emacs

I find myself using the <kbd>meta</kbd> + <kbd>arrow</kbd> keys constantly.

When I am editing code, it would be nice if I could count underscores as words so that when I decide to rename a variable it goes to the character right after the underscore.

For example, if I have a variable named `workout_disabled_color`, and I press <kbd>meta</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd>, and my cursor is currently at the end of "color", then it would go to the left of the character `c`.

Is anybody aware of how I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try modifying `nxhtml-mode-hook`.

```
(add-hook 'nxhtml-mode-hook
          (lambda () (modify-syntax-entry ?_ "w")))
```